# Gatsby React Netlify Form Button Not Working

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, gatsby, netlify

I cant seem to get the form on creditgenie.us to work. I'm using Gatsby.js and Netlify to host the site. Netlify sees the form but the button to submit doesn't work. I've tried removing the consts and making the form just pure HTML but that doesn't seem to work either. Another solution I tried was implementing the , , and  within the consts but did not work. I'm pretty sure the issue is with the button not following through with the input of the data.

Code:

```
<HeaderForm name="contact" method="post" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
  <HeaderInput name="email" placeholder="Your email" type="text"/>
  <HeaderButton> Early access </HeaderButton>
</HeaderForm>
```

CSS:

```
const HeaderForm = styled.form`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 16px;

  @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.screen.sm}) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

const HeaderInput = styled.input`
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: ${props => props.theme.color.primary};
  line-height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  height: 60px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #828282;
  border-image: initial;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  outline: 0px;
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: inset ${props => props.theme.color.secondary} 0px 0px 0px 2px;
  }
  @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.screen.md}) {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
  @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.screen.sm}) {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
`

const HeaderButton = styled.button`
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #8361FF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
  outline: 0px;
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: rgba(110, 120, 152, 0.22) 0px 2px 10px 0px;
  }
  @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.screen.md}) {
  }
  @media (max-width: ${props => props.theme.screen.sm}) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
```

Comment: `handleSubmit` def? handler called?

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for is right here: https://dev.to/travislramos/how-to-use-netlify-forms-with-gatsby-4c52